# What is the ObjectController analogue of ArrayController.itemController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

`ArrayController.itemController` wraps each individual item in the controller's content with an ObjectController. Is there an analogue on `ObjectController` to wrap a property's value in a controller?

If there there is no direct analogue on `ObjectController`, what would be the recommended way to use an `ObjectController` to wrap a model's property in another contorller?

Here's what I was doing at first:

```
App.BlogPostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  comments: function(){
    return App.CommentsController.create({
      model: this.get('model.comments')
    });
  }.property()
});
```

It's pretty straightforward, but it falls apart if `model.comments` is replaced. So I've changed it to respond to changes:

```
App.BlogPostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  comments: function(){
    var commentsController = this.get('_commentsController');
    if (!commentsController){
      commentsController = App.CommentsController.create();
      this.set('_commentsController', commentsController);
    }
    commentsController.set('model', this.get('model.comments'));
    return commentsController;
  }.property('model.comments')
});
```

Which seems to work (though I imagine there are problems I haven't yet uncovered), but it feels rather inelegant. Is there a better way of doing this?

*Edit*:

Another option would be to do:

```
App.BlogPostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {...};
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.controllerFor('comments').set('content', model.get('comments'));
  }
});

App.BlogPostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs : ['comments']
});
```

This seems like it might be a bit more "Ember-istic", but it's also a little more convoluted and requires changing template references from `{{comments}}` to `{{controllers.comments}}`. So it still feels like there should maybe be something a bit more straightforward yet still idiomatic...?

Answer (score 0):

`{{render 'templateName' model.property}}`

The property will be the model for the TemplateNameController.  `templateName` is the template that will be used for rendering.

Comment: So maybe I should have given more context: your solution works well for a hierarchy of controller/view pairs, but I'm trying to make sure I have my head wrapped around how to render a hierarchy of nested components. It seemed like I should first set up the controller hierarchy to ensure the properties expected by the components were available. Then, once the controller hierarchy was in place, pass all the data into the top-most component. But I guess I'm still missing something?